# Requisição SOAP apresentando erro

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Estou tentando realizar uma requisição SOAP em http://www.ieptb.com.br/ws/serverTabelionatos.php.

No entanto não estou conseguindo realizar a requisição com sucesso. As únicas informações que me fornecem é:

```
Name: consulta_cenprot
Binding: serverTabelionatosBinding
Endpoint: http://www.ieptb.com.br/ws/serverTabelionatos.php
SoapAction: urn:serverTabelionatos#consulta
Style: rpc
Input:
  use: encoded
  namespace: urn:serverTabelionatos
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: consulta_cenprotRequest
  parts:
    tipo_doc: xsd:string
    documento: xsd:string
Output:
  use: encoded
  namespace: urn:serverTabelionatos
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: consulta_cenprotResponse
  parts:
    return: xsd:string
Namespace: urn:serverTabelionatos
Transport: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
Documentation: Realiza a consulta de um documento na base de dados
```

A requisição que estou tentando realizar é a seguinte

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.ieptb.com.br/ws/serverTabelionatos.php",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "\r\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\r\n<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:tns=\"urn:serverTabelionatos\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" targetNamespace=\"urn:serverTabelionatos\">\r\n<types>\r\n<xsd:schema targetNamespace=\"urn:serverTabelionatos\"\r\n>\r\n <xsd:import namespace=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" />\r\n <xsd:import namespace=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" />\r\n <xsd:complexType name=\"vEstados\">\r\n  <xsd:complexContent>\r\n   <xsd:restriction base=\"SOAP-ENC:Array\">\r\n    <xsd:attribute ref=\"SOAP-ENC:arrayType\" wsdl:arrayType=\"tns:vEstados[]\"/>\r\n   </xsd:restriction>\r\n  </xsd:complexContent>\r\n </xsd:complexType>\r\n</xsd:schema>\r\n</types>\r\n\r\n<message name=\"consulta_cenprotRequest\">\r\n  <part name=\"tipo_doc\" type=\"xsd:string\" default=\"CPF\" />\r\n  <part name=\"documento\" type=\"xsd:string\" default=\"CPF AQUI\" /></message>\r\n<portType name=\"serverTabelionatosPortType\">\r\n  <operation name=\"consulta_cenprot\">\r\n    <documentation>Realiza a consulta de um documento na base de dados</documentation>\r\n    <input message=\"tns:consulta_cenprotRequest\"/>\r\n    <output message=\"tns:consulta_cenprotResponse\"/>\r\n  </operation>\r\n</portType>\r\n<binding name=\"serverTabelionatosBinding\" type=\"tns:serverTabelionatosPortType\">\r\n  <soap:binding style=\"rpc\" transport=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http\"/>\r\n  <operation name=\"consulta_cenprot\">\r\n    <soap:operation soapAction=\"urn:serverTabelionatos#consulta\" style=\"rpc\"/>\r\n    <input><soap:body use=\"encoded\" namespace=\"urn:serverTabelionatos\" encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"/></input>\r\n    <output><soap:body use=\"encoded\" namespace=\"urn:serverTabelionatos\" encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"/></output>\r\n  </operation>\r\n</binding>\r\n<service name=\"serverTabelionatos\">\r\n  <port name=\"serverTabelionatosPort\" binding=\"tns:serverTabelionatosBinding\">\r\n    <soap:address location=\"http://www.ieptb.com.br/ws/serverTabelionatos.php\"/>\r\n  </port>\r\n</service>\r\n</definitions>",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/xml",
    "postman-token: 7b5507d8-5af4-a2c2-2831-991f3f313ac8"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

O XML da requisição é o seguinte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:serverTabelionatos" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:serverTabelionatos">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:serverTabelionatos"
>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
 <xsd:complexType name="vEstados">
  <xsd:complexContent>
   <xsd:restriction base="SOAP-ENC:Array">
    <xsd:attribute ref="SOAP-ENC:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:vEstados[]"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:complexContent>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>

<message name="consulta_cenprotRequest">
  <part name="tipo_doc" type="xsd:string" default="CPF" />
  <part name="documento" type="xsd:string" default="CPF AQUI" /></message>
<portType name="serverTabelionatosPortType">
  <operation name="consulta_cenprot">
    <documentation>Realiza a consulta de um documento na base de dados</documentation>
    <input message="tns:consulta_cenprotRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:consulta_cenprotResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="serverTabelionatosBinding" type="tns:serverTabelionatosPortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="consulta_cenprot">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:serverTabelionatos#consulta" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:serverTabelionatos" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:serverTabelionatos" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/></output>
  </operation>
</binding>
<service name="serverTabelionatos">
  <port name="serverTabelionatosPort" binding="tns:serverTabelionatosBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://www.ieptb.com.br/ws/serverTabelionatos.php"/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

O erro que está retornando é o seguinte:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"></faultactor>
            <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">Operation &apos;&apos; is not defined in the WSDL for this service</faultstring>
            <detail xsi:type="xsd:string"></detail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um erro muito comum que vejo, pelo menos no PHP, são os desenvolvedores tentando usar SOAP com curl ou Guzzle e montando o XML na mão.

Não é necessário nada disso, o PHP tem um cliente SOAP nativo que elimina todo esse trabalho.

Basta habilitar ou instalar a extensão do SOAP (no Windows, descomentar a linha `extension=php_soap.dll` ou no Ubuntu `apt-get install php-soap`) e utilizar a classe [`SoapClient`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php):

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('http://www.ieptb.com.br/ws/serverTabelionatos.php?wsdl', [
    'login' => 'seu_username',
    'password' => 'senha',
]);

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Ao chamar `$client->__getFunctions()` o PHP vai ler todas as funções definidas no WSDL e você pode chamá-la diretamente no seu código, como se fosse um objeto PHP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso desse webservice, tentei chamar o método abaixo:

```
echo $client->cartorios_participantes('sp');
```

Porém como não tenho as credencias para usar o serviço, recebi o retorno `Falha na autenticação`.

Consulte com o serviço como você pode realizar a autenticação, meu palpite é passando como um array o login e o password, mas isso pode variar de acordo com o serviço.

Comment: A resposta fica muito melhor quando o cara entende de PHP :)

Comment: Sem dúvida muito bom o esclarecimento

Answer (score 5):

Parece que você está misturando o WSDL com seu body de request.

Acredito que o body que você deseja enviar para chamar a operação `consulta_cenprot` seria como o abaixo:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:serverTabelionatos">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:consulta_cenprot soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <tipo_doc xsi:type="xsd:string">CPF</tipo_doc>
         <documento xsi:type="xsd:string">000000191</documento>
      </urn:consulta_cenprot>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

O [WSDL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) (Web Services Description Language), como o próprio nome diz, é a descrição de um web service, um contrato, onde são definidas as operações disponíveis, bem como as informações que devem ser enviadas e serão recebidas em cada request/response.

Para realizar as chamadas para o serviço, utiliza-se o protocolo [SOAP](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) (Simple Object Access Protocol), esse protocolo possui estrutura padrão como a que eu mostrei acima.